# in jquery, how to select current element's first child?

Tags: jquery

$(this) //this refer to the elem
how to get the first child of 'this'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).children().eq(0)
```

or

```
$(this).children(':first')
```

or

```
$(this).children(':eq(0)')
```

or simply without jQuery:

```
this.firstChild
```